# Accessing Remote Mysql via c# from local pc

Tags: c#, mysql, remote-access

I am working on a winform application on C#. Now i have to access a remote mysql database. Well i have a paid server and added my ip address in remote access ip address list.

But still i am not able to access remote database. I want to know whats the way then, what would be the connection string in C#. Any idea would be helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have had partly success accessing my MySQL remotely by using Toad MySQL. Are you able to access it through your DB manger?

Comment: Can you successfully connect to the server using tools like SQLYOG?

Comment: You didn't tell if/which connector you are using. Are you using the official .NET connector from Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/) is a list of connection string settings for MySQL

If they don't work, check your firewall settings, also try via the MySQL command prompt.